# How are these layers like LCD added in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

How are these layers like "LCD" added in Altium Designer?
My Altium version is 21.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be new layers added and then given names to suit their application. Or they might have had other names and got renamed like this: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your an answer